# Understanding Javadoc for executeLargeUpdate about UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, jdbc

I am fairly new to Java and I was reading documentation for [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeLargeUpdate-java.lang.String-) class, and came across the `executeLargeUpdate()`

> The default implementation will throw UnsupportedOperationException

```
default long executeLargeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException
```

The default implementation here states that it throws SQLException, and checking the base class for `SQLException`, I found it is `Exception` and `UnsupportedOperationException` is child class of `RuntimeException`.

I am not able to understand what does the above line mean? The default implementation will throw means what? Please help me understand!

Comment: It means exactly that, calling `executeLargeUpdate` will throw the - unchecked - `UnsupportedOperationException`. This is the default behaviour of `Statement` unless the JDBC driver implementation supports the method.

Comment: Personally, I think it is a design error, and the default implementation should have thrown `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` (like other optional methods in JDBC introduced in earlier JDBC specification versions), but the rest of the JDBC-EG disagreed.

Comment: Your point seems completely valid to me. JDBC-EG, what's that?

Comment: JDBC Expert Group, the group of people who discuss and maintain the JDBC specification as part of the JCP (Java Community Process), [JSR-221](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Statement` is not a class but an interface. Since Java 8, interfaces can provide "default" implementations for its methods. This means that when you implement the interface, you don't have to write an implementation for all its methods. You can choose to use the default implementation of methods marked with `default`.

The method in question here is such a method. The default implementation is to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The `throws SQLException` clause has nothing to do with the default implementation. It just tells callers that when calling this method, beware that a `SQLException` is likely to be thrown, please handle that.

Implementers of `Statement` can choose not to implement `executeLargeUpdate`, in which case when called, this method will throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`. That's what "the default implementation will throw..." means.

Comment: Great..Thanks understood it :)